# How do I clone a gist using https:// instead of git://

Tags: gist

At my office we are not able to connect to github using git:// urls. For the regular repositories we just juse the https:// url and we're fine.

For gist there does not appear to be a way to access the gist via an https:// url.

BTW, I cannot seem to find any github documentation about gist ... I recall reading a page on github(?) about gist, but for the life of me I cannot find anything on the site itself that documents gist ... of course google is useless as gist show up everywhere ... but no documentation links:(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried both `git clone git@gist.github.com:1895307.git gist-1895307` and `git clone git://gist.github.com/1895307.git gist-1895307` to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only fing a way to get the raw file(s) through http :

```
GET http://gist.github.com/raw/:gist_id/:filename
```

found on the gist API page of github:

[http://develop.github.com/p/gist.html (archived copy)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120618030138/http://develop.github.com/p/gist.html)

Comment: Gack! Better than nothing...Thanks for the pointer to the docs ... I was trying to hard to find gist-specific documentation:)

Comment: That API page link is broken.

Answer (score 15):

You can configure git to use `https://` globally by running running `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` or by adding the following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "https://"]
  insteadOf = git://
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use the gist's URL without any trouble. This:

`git clone https://gist.github.com/{user}/{gist id}`

works fine for me, where `https://gist.github.com/{user}/{gist id}` is the actual URL of the gist. I'm about to clone and and to push. It doesn't use my SSH keys to push -- I have to give my username and password -- but otherwise it works fine.